# Non nullable instance field must be initalised

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

im new to Dart-flutter.

i have watching a tutorial video from udemy course writing in dart pad

so i also wrote in dartpad. but it showing error in it.

this is the code wrote in udemy..

```
import 'dart:convert';
  
 void main(){  
  var rawJson = '{"url": "https://helo.com","id": 2}';
  var parsedJson = json.decode(rawJson);
  var imageModel = new ImageModel.fromJson(parsedJson);
     
  print(imageModel.url);
 }

class ImageModel{
  int id;
  String url;
 
  ImageModel.fromJson(parsedJson) {
    id = parsedJson['id'];
    url = parsedJson['url'];
  }
  
   ImageModel(this.id, this.url);
}
```

in that video it runs, but for me it shows error as

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
Info: Compiling with sound null safety
Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:dartpad_sample/main.dart'.
lib/main.dart:15:3:
Error: This constructor should initialize field 'id' because its type 'int' doesn't allow null.
  ImageModel.fromJson(parsedJson) {
  ^
lib/main.dart:12:7:
Info: 'id' is defined here.
  int id;
      ^^
lib/main.dart:15:3:
Error: This constructor should initialize field 'url' because its type 'String' doesn't allow null.
  ImageModel.fromJson(parsedJson) {
  ^
lib/main.dart:13:10:
Info: 'url' is defined here.
  String url;
         ^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

i have no idea what the problem is..
can you guys help me to troubleshoot the error

Comment: Initialize the `id` and `url` fields in the initializer list (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're compiling with null safety, you may change to this:

```dart
int? id;
String? url;
```

For further info about null safety, please refer to this link https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 0):

Try using null safe code:
eg:

int? id;
String? url;

Answer (score 0):

**You will try like this**

```
import 'dart:convert';
 class ImageModel{
  final int id;
  final String url;

  ImageModel({required this.id, required this.url});

 factory ImageModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
  return ImageModel(
    id: parsedJson['id'] as int,
     url: parsedJson['url'] as String,
    );
   }   
  }

 void main() {
   var rawJson = '{"url": "https://helo.com","id": 2}';
   var parsedJson = json.decode(rawJson);
   
   print(parsedJson['url']);
   print(parsedJson['id']);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably watching tutorial that was recorded before [null-safety introduction](https://dart.dev/null-safety) in Dart (null-safety is a Dart feature that helps prevent NullRefference exceptions in runtime).

You can either go with nullable values (like @Sowat Kheang suggested in another answer) for `id` and `url` in `ImageModel` class (change `String` to `String?` and `int` to `int?`). Then you will be fine, but it defeats the purpose of null-safety.

Or you can change your code so it will handle null values in proper way. Code will look something like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
  
 void main(){  
  var rawJson = '{"url": "https://helo.com","id": 2}';
  var parsedJson = json.decode(rawJson);
  var imageModel = ImageModel.fromJson(parsedJson);
     
  print(imageModel.url);
 }

class ImageModel{
  // Make your fields 'final' if you don't plan to change them later
  // this will make your life easier and is a good practice.
  final int id;
  final String url;

  // we add curly braces to make arguments named 
  // and add 'required' keyword to indicate that constructor can't be called
  // without actually passing arguments into it
  ImageModel({required this.id, required this.url});
 
 // here we use factory constructor that will call our default constructor
 // it's also a good practice to specify type of a variable if you know it (Map<String, dynamic> in this case)
  factory ImageModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    
    // since we don't know for sure if 'parsedJson' has key 'id' 
    // we would add '??' — null checking operator.
    // So if parsedJson['id'] is null, value -1 will be passed 
    // to the constructor. Same with 'parsedJson['url']'.
    return ImageModel(
        id: parsedJson['id'] ?? -1,
        url: parsedJson['url'] ?? '');
  }
  

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var rawJson = '{"url": "https://helo.com","id": 2}';
```

Actually it is a Sting Json and Encoding is not perform properly  So follow the step..

1. `Map data={"url": "https://helo.com","id": 2};`
2. Encode that data.   `json.encode(data);`
3. Now the Encoding is done then you can send the data any server if you have..
4. When you get back data then... `json.decode(rawData)`
5. Then parsing work properly